# How much of the content comes with the original game purchase

Tags: defiance

I am skeptical about getting Defiance, since I have heard that the a lot of content in the game has to be purchased as cash shop or DLC. How much of the content comes with the original game purchase?

Comment: There's a free weekend through Steam right now; why not try it and let us know?

Comment: I will give it a try!  The question still stands for players that have progessed far into the game.

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying it's not a valid question!  I'm just saying that you have an opportunity to answer your own question right now!

Answer (score 2):

When you buy Defiance you will be able to play the whole game. The in-game shop contains new vehicle colors, outfit just to change the look of your character and XP boost. buying any of them wont make you stronger in either PVE or PVP.
As for the DLC here's a part of what they said about it.

> We do our DLCs a bit differently with Defiance. Every time we do a
>   DLC, of which we have 5 planned within the next year, we have a free
>   component, a paid component and a store update. The free part is for
>   everyone. We want people to be playing with their friends; we don’t
>   like to isolate players.
>
> That doesn’t mean there won’t be exclusive content in the DLCs, quite
>   the contrary. The difference is that you can usually bring your
>   friends with you. The catch is that they can’t directly benefit from
>   all of it, like DLC specific loot or gain abilities.

[The First DLC Info](http://community.defiance.com/en/2013/05/09/you-just-keep-coming-back-for-more-but-now-what-lets-talk-potential/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually as far as I know and tried the DLCs contain very little additional content.
The main content - especially if we are taking about 'story missions' - is part of the original game, not DLSs. Although they say in DLC info it does contain some new story content.

The 1st DLC (the only one released so far) for example doesn't add any new parts of the world. Just (probably) few new quests, happening on 'old' game map.